# Video files (AVI) tags editor?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, editing, tag

I would like to change tags of ordinary video files (AVI container). Are there any video file (AVI) tag editors available in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a partial answer in [this ubuntuforums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8031373#post8031373) .

There are examples using ffmpeg and mencoder, which "works with mp4,avi,mpeg,wmv1,wmv2,mkv output" .

The two examples [cor2y](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=59168) gives are:

```
 ffmpeg -i file.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata title="Dancing Bear" -metadata comment="Title Created Using FFmpeg metadata tag" outputfile.avi
```

and

```
 mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy file,avi -info name="Dancing Bear" -info comment="File Title Created with Mencoder Info tag "  -o outputfile.avi
```

Comment: Thank you for hint. However, I would like to edit tags by software with GUI. I found that VLC player 'should' edit tags, but it doesn't :(